# Como aumentar o número de iterações no R?

Tags: r

Estou trabalhando com um modelo estatístico que ajusta uma curva aos dados de uma determinada doença. Porém ao rodar o código obtenho que o número de iterações excedeu o máximo de 50. Segue baixo o CMR e o erro informado:

```
Error in nls(formula = Contaminated ~ a * Int^b, data, start = list(a = 1,  : 
  número de iterações excedeu o máximo de 50
```

Segue o cógido:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
data <- structure(list(Day = c("26/feb", "29/feb", "04/mar", "05/mar", 
                               "06/mar", "07/mar", "08/mar", "10/mar", "11/mar", "12/mar", "13/mar", 
                               "14/mar", "15/mar", "16/mar", "17/mar", "18/mar", "19/mar", "20/mar", 
                               "21/mar", "22/mar", "23/mar", "24/mar", "25/mar"), Contaminated = c(1L, 
                                                                                                   2L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 19L, 25L, 34L, 52L, 81L, 98L, 121L, 176L, 234L, 
                                                                                                   291L, 428L, 621L, 904L, 1128L, 1546L, 1891L, 2201L, 2433L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    -23L))
setDT(data)
data[,Day:= as.Date(Day, "%d/%b")]
data[,Int := as.integer(Day)-min(as.integer(Day))]
nls(formula = Contaminated ~ a * Int ^ b, data,start=list(a=1,b=1))
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada na função `nls.control()` que permite de definir o numero de iterações.

Comment: Eu utilizei a função e aumentei o número de iterações,porém o erro continua.Console ao utilizar 
a função:
[link](https://imgur.com/a/wC2QIZg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explicação

O erro ocorre porque a transformação para Data na variável `Day` pode gerar `NA`s dependendo do `locale` da sua máquina.

O NA gerado nas duas primeiras datas (que tem "fev") faz com que toda a variável `Int` fique NA (por `min(Day)` vai retornar NA) e ai o resultado não converge com 50, 100 ou mesmo 1000 interações (observem que no exemplo do MarcusNunes o modelo convergiu com apenas 48 interações então sequer precisava do argumento `nls.control`)

## Detalhes

O primeiro passo do seu processamento de dados está em transformar uma variável de texto para data. No meu computador, que usa padrões brasileiros, tenho o seguinte resultado quando tento converter para `date` o vetor de texto passado na pergunta:

```
as.Date(c("26/feb", "29/feb"), format = "%d/%b")
#> [1] NA NA
```

Posso conferir o padrão usado pelo meu computador com o seguinte comando:

```
Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
#> [1] "pt_BR.UTF-8"
```

E, como se pode perceber do resultado acima, meu computador utiliza padrões brasileiros para os quais "feb" não é um mês. Vejamos quais os meses válidos.

```
format(Sys.Date() - (1:12 *31), "%b")
#> [1] "Fev" "Jan" "Dez" "Nov" "Out" "Set" "Ago" "Jul" "Jun" "Mai" "Abr" "Mar"
```

Agora que sei que devo usar "fev" (de "fevereiro") no lugar de "feb" (de "february"), basta alterar o vetor usado inicialmente na definição dos dados para obter o resultado esperado.

```
as.Date(c("26/fev", "29/fev"), format = "%d/%b")
#> [1] "2020-02-26" "2020-02-29"
```

Nas outras datas não houve erro por "Mar" serve tanto para "Março" como para "March"

E se eu tiver muitos dados e não puder alterar o valor de cada dado de entrada? Neste caso você pode especificar para o `R` qual `locale` ele deve usar.

#### Atenção, cuidado em alterar o locale usado pelo R! Isso pode fazer outras partes do seu código parar de funcionar!

Pelo motivo acima recomendo usar pacote `lubridate`, que usa a informação do `locale` sem alterar o padrão usado pelo `R`.

```
library(lubridate)
lubridate::dmy(paste0(c("26/feb", "29/feb"), "/2020"), locale = "en_US.UTF-8")
#> [1] "2020-02-26" "2020-02-29"

# Ou deixar ele se virar sozinho
lubridate::dmy(paste0(c("26/feb", "29/feb"), "/2020"))
#> [1] "2020-02-26" "2020-02-29"

# Um terminado em V outro em B
lubridate::dmy(paste0(c("26/fev", "29/feb"), "/2020"))
#> [1] "2020-02-26" "2020-02-29
```

Uma vez que sua variável `Day` esteja bem, o restante do código funciona.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
data <- structure(
  list(
    Day = c("26/feb", "29/feb", "04/mar", "05/mar", 
            "06/mar", "07/mar", "08/mar", "10/mar", "11/mar", "12/mar", "13/mar", 
            "14/mar", "15/mar", "16/mar", "17/mar", "18/mar", "19/mar", "20/mar", 
            "21/mar", "22/mar", "23/mar", "24/mar", "25/mar"), 
    Contaminated = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 19L, 25L, 34L, 52L, 81L, 
                     98L, 121L, 176L, 234L, 291L, 428L, 621L, 904L, 
                     1128L, 1546L, 1891L, 2201L, 2433L)
    ), 
  class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -23L))
setDT(data)
data[,Day:= dmy(paste0(Day, "/2020"))]
data[,Int := as.integer(Day)-min(as.integer(Day))]
nls(formula = Contaminated ~ a * Int ^ b, data,start=list(a=1,b=1))

#> Nonlinear regression model
#> model: Contaminated ~ a * Int^b
#> data: data
#> a         b 
#> 2.272e-05 5.571e+00 
#> residual sum-of-squares: 123279
#> 
#> Number of iterations to convergence: 48 
#> Achieved convergence tolerance: 8.188e-07
```

Comment: Genial,nunca passou pela minha cabeça que o erro se dava pela região que estou. Muito obrigado,agora estou tentando resolver o erro que da ao ajustar a curva ao adicionar novos dados,fiz até uma pergunta sobre isso aqui.

Answer (score 2):

Basta usar a função `nls.control` dentro da função `nls` para obter o resultado desejado:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

setDT(data)
data[,Day:= as.Date(Day, "%d/%b")]
data[,Int := as.integer(Day)-min(as.integer(Day))]
nls(formula = Contaminated ~ a * Int ^ b, data,start=list(a=1,b=1))

ajuste <- nls(formula = Contaminated ~ a * Int ^ b, 
              data, 
              start=list(a=1, b=1),
              nls.control(maxiter = 100))
```

Abaixo estão os coeficientes do modelo ajustado:

```
summary(ajuste)

Formula: Contaminated ~ a * Int^b

Parameters:
   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
a 2.272e-05  1.579e-05   1.439    0.165    
b 5.571e+00  2.127e-01  26.191   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 76.62 on 21 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 48 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.182e-07
```

Não sei porque nossos computadores são diferentes, mas eu obtive convergência com 48 passos.

Por fim, segue um gráfico comparando os dados analisados com a curva ajustada:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Day, y = Contaminated)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(x = Day, y = predict(ajuste, data$Int))) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Continua dando o mesmo erro e agora também diz que eu excedi as 100 iterações,o engraçado é que no rdrr.io o código roda sem problema algum,mesmo sem o ajuste.
Segue o meu console:
[link](https://imgur.com/a/LF1y6bI)

Comment: Outra dúvida,o senhor sabe me dizer como eu poderia prever o número de contaminados escolhendo uma data? Tentei usar a função predict,porém não consegui encaixar.

Comment: O teu R está na última versão? Aqui estou usando a versão 3.6.3. Quanto à predição, utilize `predict(ajuste, data.frame(Int =as.integer(as.Date("2020-03-25"))-min(as.integer(data$Day))))` e substitua `"2020-03-25"` pela data de sua preferência.

Comment: Estou utilizando a 3.6.3 também e testei com a 3.6.0 também,não sei por que está dando esse erro. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Não importa o que eu tente não consigo que o console não dê o erro de iterações no meu R,no rdrr.io consigo rodar sem problemas.